# Token Expired of vidyo.io

Tags: vidyo

I am using free trail on https://vidyo.io/ so if i will pay them then my token will be expired or not ?***strong text***

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A token is used to authenticate entry into a room. When you create one, there is an expiration time that is set. Once that expiration time has passed, then that token is no longer valid.

Of course if your trial promo minutes have expired, then you will need to subscribe to the Vidyo.io service in order to generate valid tokens.

Comment: thank you for immediate reply, I have a little bit confusing, if I subscribe the channel then my token will be expired or not?

Comment: A new token should be generated for each participant that wants to join a room. You will not be able to generate a valid token unless you either have promotional minutes in your account or are subscribed to the service. As I mentioned earlier, the token itself has an expiration time which is specified when its generated.